# Use local Dockerfile in a GitHub action?

Tags: docker, github-actions

I would like to setup a GitHub Action to build my project and run tests locally. As I use `.devcontainer` I have a `Dockerfile` in `.devcontainer/Dockerfile` that provide everything I need to build my project.

Now I would like to write a GitHub Action to build the project on every push. Locally I would have done this:

```
docker build -t local - < .devcontainer/Dockerfile
docker run -it -v $(pwd):/srv -w/srv local make test
```

GitHub actions looks cumbersome, but I eventually wrote this:

```
on: push
jobs:
  build:
    name: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: check out repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: build project
        container:
          image: ".devcontainer/Dockerfile"
          volumes:
            - .:/srv
        run: make test
```

Unfortunately it does not like the `container` keyword.

Any clues?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The container key is designed for running publicly available dockerized actions, and is available under the [`job.<job_id>`](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idcontainer) key, not the `steps` key. You do not need it to accomplish your task.

The GitHub runners have an [extensive list of software installed](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#supported-software) already, including docker and docker compose.

You can easily run the same commands you run locally in your GitHub workflow.

```
steps:
- name: Check out code
  uses: actions/checkout@v3
- name: Build docker images
  run: docker build -t local < .devcontainer/Dockerfile
- name: Run tests
  run: docker run -it -v $PWD:/srv -w/srv local make test
```

I am running most of my workflows like this, only using docker-compose, so you end up with cleaner workflows:

```
steps:
- name: Check out code
  uses: actions/checkout@v3
- name: Build docker images
  run: docker compose build
- name: Setup database
  run: docker compose run setup
- name: Run tests
  run: docker compose run test
```

Comment: what do your `docker compose setup|test` do? Also, how to you check in github that the tests inside of docker passed or failed?

Comment: @d56 `setup` and `test` are services defined in docker-compose.yml. `docker-compose run test` will relay the status code of your command, so if your test suite exits with status 1 (anything but 0 means error), that's the exit status that GitHub will see. This works 

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to build, publish and re-use a Docker image based on your `Dockerfile`.

I would advise to create a custom `build-and-publish-docker.yml` action following the Github documentation: [Publishing Docker images](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/publishing-packages/publishing-docker-images).

Assuming your repository is public, you should be able to automatically upload your image to `ghcr.io` without any required configuration. As an alternative, it's also possible to publish the image to Docker Hub.

Once your image is built and published (based on the `on` event of the action previously created, which can be triggered manually also), you just need to update your `tests.yml` action so it uses the custom Docker image. Again, here is a pretty good documentation page about the `container` option: [Running jobs in a container](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/running-jobs-in-a-container).

As an example, I'm sharing what I used in a personal repository:

- [`Dockerfile`](https://github.com/Delgan/qml-format/blob/a57ccf9991ca3e210d2ec3c97156c5fb4bb66227/dockerfiles/ubuntu/Dockerfile): the Docker image to be built on CI
- [`docker.yml`](https://github.com/Delgan/qml-format/blob/a57ccf9991ca3e210d2ec3c97156c5fb4bb66227/.github/workflows/docker.yml): the action to build the Docker image
- [`lint.yml`](https://github.com/Delgan/qml-format/blob/a57ccf9991ca3e210d2ec3c97156c5fb4bb66227/.github/workflows/lint.yml): the action using the built Docker image