# Run GitHub workflow on Docker image with a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, github-actions

I would like to run my CI on a Docker image. How should I write my `.github/workflow/main.yml`?

```
name: CI
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    name: build
    runs:
      using: 'docker'
      image: '.devcontainer/Dockerfile'
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Build
        run: make
```

I get the error:

```
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/main.yml 
     (Line: 11, Col: 5): Unexpected value 'runs'
```

I managed to make it work but with an ugly workaround:

```
  build:
    name: Build Project
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Build docker images
        run: > 
           docker build . -t foobar 
           -f .devcontainer/Dockerfile
      - name: Build exam
        run: >
           docker run -v 
           $GITHUB_WORKSPACE:/srv 
           -w/srv foobar make
```

Side question: where can I find the documentation about this? All I found is how to write actions.

Comment: Documents for Creating a Docker container action https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-docker-container-action

Comment: I don’t want to create a container action :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a container to run your actions, you can use something like this:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      container:
        image: docker://{host}/{image}:{tag}
      steps:
        ...
```

[Here is an example](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/ritchie-formulas-scheduler-demo/blob/main/.github/workflows/4-formulas-scheduler-container.yml).

If you want more details about the `jobs.<job_id>.container` and its sub-fields, you can check [the official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idcontainer).

*Note that you can also use docker images at the step level: [Example](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/06-docker-image-workflow.yml).*

Answer (score 2):

<sub>*I am reposting my answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61154750/use-local-dockerfile-in-a-github-action), in order to be sure to find it while Googling it.*</sub>

---

The best solution is to build, publish and re-use a Docker image based on your `Dockerfile`.

I would advise to create a custom `build-and-publish-docker.yml` action following the Github documentation: [Publishing Docker images](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/publishing-packages/publishing-docker-images).

Assuming your repository is public, you should be able to automatically upload your image to `ghcr.io` without any required configuration. As an alternative, it's also possible to publish the image to Docker Hub.

Once your image is built and published (based on the `on` event of the action previously created, which can be triggered manually also), you just need to update your `main.yml` action so it uses the custom Docker image. Again, here is a pretty good documentation page about the `container` option: [Running jobs in a container](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/running-jobs-in-a-container).

As an example, I'm sharing what I used in a personal repository:

- [`Dockerfile`](https://github.com/Delgan/qml-format/blob/a57ccf9991ca3e210d2ec3c97156c5fb4bb66227/dockerfiles/ubuntu/Dockerfile): the Docker image to be built on CI
- [`docker.yml`](https://github.com/Delgan/qml-format/blob/a57ccf9991ca3e210d2ec3c97156c5fb4bb66227/.github/workflows/docker.yml): the action to build the Docker image
- [`lint.yml`](https://github.com/Delgan/qml-format/blob/a57ccf9991ca3e210d2ec3c97156c5fb4bb66227/.github/workflows/lint.yml): the action using the built Docker image